# Does Russia impose a limit on the number of visitor visas issued to tourists in a given year?

Tags: visas, russia, event-based-effects

Next year Moscow holds the World Cup, and the number of tourists may increase. I don't have any interest in the WC, but it is likely that I must visit Russia in July.

So I wonder if Russia imposes a limit on the number of visas issued, either in a month or year. I can't apply before June, so I wonder if there is a limit and I might not obtain the visa because of reaching the limit.

Comment: Or in the broader scope, is it common that countries that require visas for tourists set the limit?

Comment: Russia will be allowing visa free access for World Cup Ticket holders provided they register as a fan online. This will obviously be where they will be blocking undesirables. So visas should not be affected, too much.

Comment: See details here http://metro.co.uk/2017/10/05/will-you-need-a-visa-to-go-to-the-russia-2018-world-cup-and-how-to-get-a-fan-id-card-6978744/

Comment: No, there is no limit as to how many visas you can apply for. For most countries, you can apply for an many visas you would need.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing. As long as you're eligible to get a tourist visa, you can get it regardless of how many other tourists have already applied.

Source: Never heard of such practice; scooped a few web sites about Russian visas, they don't talk about such limitation.